# Retrieve latest revision ID given a URL to Git repo?

Tags: git

So I know it's possible to retrieve the revision ID from the command line while inside a Git repo:

```
git rev-list HEAD | head -n1
```

Is there anything that would allow you to do something like the following:

```
git rev-list HEAD git@some.path.to.your.repo:user/repo.git | head -n1
```

Or would you specifically have to clone the repo and be in that directory in the terminal in order to retrieve this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git rev-parse HEAD` is simpler and produces the same answer, but what it gives you is the hash ID of the *current* revision, not necessarily the *latest* revision.  In particular, once you check out some branch, `HEAD` names the tip of that branch—which by definition is the last commit on that branch—but if you check out a historical commit, you end up in "detached HEAD" mode, and `HEAD` now names that historical commit.  So you only get *a* (not necessarily *the*) latest revision if you're on some branch: you get that branch's latest revision hash ID.

That said, you can use `git ls-remote` to ask any Git server to tell you what it would first tell your Git repository (for `git fetch` purposes) if you had your Git connect to it:

```
git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Note that `git clone` consists of creating a new repository, adding a remote-name/URL pair, fetching branches and tags, and then checking out some branch.  Therefore, if you skip straight to the "fetch" step and then cut it off after it's told you what branch and tag names *they* have and what the hash IDs are for those branches and tags, that gets you the answer you wanted.  So `git ls-remote` is the command you want.

Comment: What if I want to do this and the repo has multiple branches? How can I specify a specific branch when doing this?

Comment: You can pick a specific reference, yes: `git ls-remote <url> refs/heads/xyz` gets you the xyz branch, `git ls-remote <url> refs/tags/v2.1` gets you tag v2.1, and so on. Or you can just parse the output lines. Note that you can tell which branch they recommend a `git clone` operation check out at the end, provided they support the modern `--symref` protocol, using `git ls-remote --symref <url> HEAD`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much.